# How does the relationship between velocity and net force affect the direction of a moving object?

Tags: kinematics

I already know that for a moving object with velocity $\ v_i$,and has a net force, $\ F_{net}$, the trajectory of the object will start with the direction of $\ v_i$ and gradually deflect to the direction of $\ F_{net}$.

My question is, is there any way to determine the deflecting angle at a certain moment by given vector quantity $\ F_{net}$ and $\ v_i$?

I am thinking, to find the resulting direction, the contacting time is required because this way, we can find the instant velocity that generated by the acceleration at the moment. Further, find the vector quantity of the  resulting velocity, which would lead to determine the angle. I am on the right track?

Any thought or idea is appreciated!!! Thanks~

Comment: The direction of applied net force should coincide with the body's velocity. What do you mean by "gradual deflection" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the total change in momentum is given by the integral of the force in time:

$\Delta p = \int _{t_i} ^{t_f} F(t') dt'$

This is the general formula.  For simple forces, this can be integrated by hand to get an analytic result, but if the force depends sensitively on the position or velocity, numerical integration may be the easiest route.